# Could powered exoskeletons enable humans to fly?

Tags: technology, flight, anatomy

I have seen people saying that humans can't fly even with wings because our arm muscles aren't strong enough.

Given that one of the uses of powered exoskeletons is to increase strength, would this be able to provide the strength needed to fly?

By "fly" I mean bird-like with flapping wings.

Comment: Please explain why already existing ways of flying ([jetpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_pack), [microlight plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aviation), [hang glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_gliding)) do not match your requirements. Anyway, given enough power anything can fly.

Comment: my question isn't "how can humans fly" my question is "could powered exoskeletons provide the required strength"

Comment: In a way a helicopter or the things mentioned above are a powered exoskeleton. When it comes to things like these, the question is always : why has nobody done this yet.

Comment: technically a jetpack would be a powered exoskeleton....

Comment: my question isn't "how can humans fly" my question is "could powered exoskeletons provide the required strength"

Comment: What we're saying is that from a technical point of view an e.g. microlight *is* a power exoskeleton.  They may not be human-shaped extensions, but they're extensions designed to function with the human body (and not without it).

Comment: Technically, big birds don't do much wing-flapping. Instead, for the most part they glide, relying on hot air currents to carry them up. Much like a hang glider. So you could regard a hang glider as an exoskeleton enabling people to fly.

Comment: @Galastel and typically roost high up, since getting off the ground can be problematic.

Comment: @SJuan76, "With sufficient thrust, pigs fly just fine." -- [RFC 1925](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1925).

Comment: A better solution to this idea is to move to Titan, as between the denser air and lower gravity you can fly by unaided muscle power alone without problems. You only need a lightweight spacesuit, preferably something like the Space Activity Suit(the cool form fitting one).

Answer (score 6):

No, because:

1. Things that fly must be **light**, because of gravity.  (That's why bird bones are so much lighter than mammal bones, and airplanes are made of *very thin* aluminum.)
2. Powered exoskeletons are **heavy**, and designed to enhance the **legs** and **arms**.
3. Flapping wings use **chest** muscles (the Pectoralis for pulling down, and the Supracoracoideus -- who's tendons wrap over the shoulder -- to pull the wing up).
4. The chest bone structure of birds is different from humans.
5. Bird on the ground are tilted forward, and fly in an almost prone position.  Contrast that with the human vertical stature.

Powered exoskeletons would change none of that.

[image]
https://askabiologist.asu.edu/sites/default/files/resources/articles/bats/human-bird-bone-comparison-540.gif

[image]
http://yourniskayuna24.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Powered-Exoskeleton-214x300.jpg

[image]
https://www.birdwatchingdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/muscle-bound_660x745.jpg

Comment: Please consider properly attributing any used images or, even better, link them to their original source.

Comment: I find this answer lacking. Current generation of exo-skeletons are extremely primitive, more of a proof of concept than actual practical pieces of equipment. Assuming technology advances exo-skeletons can become practicle. At that point you build highly specific exo-skeletons for only a few purposes. An exo-skeleton for flying would use light materials, such as Graphene-enhanced metamaterials for lightweight but strong materials and some massive wingspans. The biggest problem would be a lightweight powersource with enough storage and output to fly for extended periods.

Comment: @Demigan even with all that... look how the bird is oriented in flight.  Humans would have to be similarly oriented.  But we're not.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T too bad the img tag dialog box doesn't do that automatically.  I'll try and find the pics again, though.

Comment: @Demigan reason #5 added.

Answer (score 3):

Answer in two parts:

1) Yes. What you're looking for is called an ornithopter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter) and powered models have been made - albeit not very successfully. Given light enough materials and powerplants you could certainly create a machine capable of flight.

2) Why? As above, ornithopters are not particularly successful (as in human-carrying ones are currently flying a few metres at a time, whilst conventional aircraft are happily cruising for thousands of miles). Humanity has been refining powered flight for the last 100+ years and has basically narrowed it down to either (a) thrust engines and a lifting surface or (b) powered rotors as these give by far the most successful results. If you want flying soldiers, you're most likely to get success using one of those two methods.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Re human bones cannot withstand forces - a machine does not exert leverage against the human bones.  Re humans are too big - the machine is as large as it needs to be.  The only difference between a machine you sit in and a powered suit is the control interface, which is arbitrary.  If powered flapping flight is possible for humans (and it is; see link) a powered flapping flight suit is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it could be done by blindly increasing power.  Even with a good sized wing and low weight, flapping is surprisingly complicated.  You're going to want an AI to help you as well.

We have made vehicles that flap their wings, like this [dragon fly robot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8tgUKro46A).  However, those simple wings are quite a lot different than bird wings are.  Bird wings have feathers, and they can often be controlled with remarkable precision.  Just take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTVigNA3KCY) from Smarter Every Day on parrots.  You can see all the motion that goes into it.  Some of this motion simply come from the topology of the feathers and doens't require thought.  The wingtips and tail, however, are heavily controlled by small muscles.  This dramatically improves the efficiency of the bird, letting it be light enough weight to function.

Your ornthopter would likely have to do similar, to cut the weight down.  You would want an AI onboard which is constantly optimizing the feathers, and somehow relaying information about that to the user to help them guide their path.

Comment: If it's an exoskeleton, there shouldn't be any need for an AI - there's a perfectly good I that can learn movement patterns with incredible dexterity.

Answer (score 1):

Not alone. Humans are too heavy to fly on their own, adding anything which increases their weight would only make things worse.

Also keep in mind that the body has to be able to withstand the forces exerted during the act of fly, thus the muscles and the bones have to be strengthened.

If instead of flying by flapping wings you aim to have sort of reaction fly then the problem becomes how to control the arms during the flight.

Comment: A powered exoskeleton could well increase the power-to-mass ratio of a human though, making flight more possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if technology could build them to work like a bird. But due to the weight it would need wingspans of 40 feet and more and take off would be a huge problem.

Flight control and all the rest would have to be worked out.

But assuming you could build an exoskeleton to do the muscle work then there is nothing stopping it being possible. It's just not the most efficient way of flying for humans.

Takeoff is a big problem, large birds either drop into the air from a height or run along flapping to gain enough speed to get lift for take off eg, swan. It's unlikely that a human could run fast enough even without balancing a 40 foot wingspan, so they would need to drop from a height.

This is all pretty dangerous, as recently as 2006 [Yves Roussea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yves_Rousseau) was severely injured in a flight attempt under controlled conditions. A fixed wing is a lot safer for obvious reasons.

Comment: Actually, the *mechanical stresses* on a 40' (flapping) wing are likely to be problematic...

Answer (score 0):

## Possibly

#### But not with current materials nor a fully humanoid shape

Consider power and energy requirements for what you intend to do. Then consider the tyranny of the square cube law.

To lift a human, jetpacks usually have a power output of about a thousand HP. You can buy a 1,050 HP one at Selfridges & Co if you have half a million pounds to spend ([seriously](https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/features/events/self-discoveries-five-things-you-dont-want-to-miss-at-selfridges-this-week-1907181/)).

1,050 HP equals 783kW. To give that much output in wing strokes would require prohibitively large wings - and the larger the wing, the more extra power you'd need to flap them, so a robotic kind of suit like Tony Stark's or real life [Yves Rossy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yves_Rossy) is out of question. Otherwise you would need a flap rate so fast that not even a male teenager on Red Bull would be able to handle. I don't know of a material that would withstand it as well.

If you had a material that were as dense as flesh or leather, maybe you could give it the shape of a [Quetzalcoatlus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatlus). The blue species in the graph below was thought to weight up to 70kg, and the bigger one could weight 250kg (y paleonthologists' estimates). By donning an ultralight suit with that shape, you could probably leap from a building and glide your way to safety.

[image: Quetzalcoatlus]

Comment: "you could probably leap from a building and glide your way to safety." But that's not, to quote the question, "bird-like with **flapping** wings."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really power.  I have a powered "exoskeleton" - AKA Piper Cherokee - that allows me to fly perfectly well.  And I could use another sort of exoskeleton - a hang glider - to fly in much the same way that large soaring birds do.

No, the real problem is flapping flight, at any scale or power level.  To do that reasonably well, you need a highly variable and controllable wing.  Birds don't fly just by flapping a stiff wing up and down.  The shape and angle are continuously changing so as to maximize lift & thrust on the downstroke while minimizing air resistance on the upstroke https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_flight  They do this with multiple joints and actuators (bones & muscles), feathers that are controllable with muscles, or which rotate in their sockets, and a complex feedback and control network (nerves & brain).

So to build a bird-like flying device, you have to duplicate all this, and make it reliable (or at least fail-safe).  Once you've done that, applying sufficient power should be relatively simple.

Another problem with having humans fly with powered exoskeletons is that our arms are in the wrong place.  They're too far forward, so we'd be tail-heavy and crash unless the exoskeleton could flap with sufficient power & speed to hover like a hummingbird.  And having our arms forced to move that fast (and probably at unnatural angles) might do considerable damage.